# How to center align the plot over the xticks when offset by hue

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart, boxplot, violin-plot

My boxplot seem not align with the x-tick of the plot. How to make the boxplot align with the x-tick?

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([['0', 0.3],['1', 0.5],['2', 0.9],
                   ['0', 0.8],['1', 0.3],['2', 0.4],
                   ['0', 0.4],['1', 0.0],['2', 0.7]])

df.columns = ['label', 'score']

label_list = ['0', '1', '2']

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
g=sns.boxplot(x='label', y='score', data=df, hue='label', hue_order=label_list)
g.legend_.remove()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add `dodge=False` into your `boxplot` line & that should fix this.
That updated code would be as below

```
g=sns.boxplot(x='label', y='score', data=df, hue='label', hue_order=label_list, dodge=False)
```

[image]

You can then play with `width` to control the width (default width is 0.8) of box plots like below

```
g=sns.boxplot(x='label', y='score', data=df, hue='label', hue_order=label_list, dodge=False, width=.2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- As stated by [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest), *remove `hue='label', hue_order=label_list`. That is responsible for shifting the boxes*.

  - Applicable to [`sns.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) and associated [axes-level categorical plots](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions).
- `hue` should be used to encode a different set of categories, not to encode the same category, `'label'`, multiple times.

  - The `'label'` category is already encoded on the x-axis. Likewise, there doesn't need to be a legend, because the information is already encoded on the x-axis.
- Following are a few citations outlining graphical perception and color usage.

  - While some packages, like `ggplot`, and `seaborn`, may encode every category on the x-axis with a color, it's better to [avoid unnecessary usage of color](https://chartio.com/learn/charts/how-to-choose-colors-data-visualization/#avoid-unnecessary-usage-of-color).
  - From [*Practical Rules for Using Color in Charts* by *Stephen Few, Perceptual Edge*](https://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/rules_for_using_color.pdf), in the **Use Color Meaningfully and with Restraint** section: the color usage in this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScEmI.png), means nothing, and should be avoided.

    - *Use color only when needed to serve a particular communication goal.*
    - *Use different colors only when they correspond to differences of meaning in the data.*
  - As a general reference, see [Graphical Perception and Graphical Methods for Analyzing Scientific Data](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1695272), *William S. Cleveland and Robert McGill*, [*New Series, Vol. 229, No. 4716 (Aug. 30, 1985), pp. 828-833 (6 pages)*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/i298770), published by: American Association for the Advancement of Science

    - [Virginia Tech](http://snoid.sv.vt.edu/%7Enpolys/projects/safas/1695272.pdf)

#### Default Plot Without `hue`

```py
ax = sns.boxplot(data=df, x='label', y='score')
_ = ax.set(title='Default Plot\nUnnecessary Use of Color')
```

[image]

#### Plot With a Single Color

```py
ax = sns.boxplot(data=df, x='label', y='score', color='tab:blue')
_ = ax.set(title='Avoid Unnecessary Use of Color')
```

[image]

---

- If the order of categories on the x-axis is important, and not correctly ordered, one of the following options can be implemented:

  1. Specify the order with the `order` parameter.

     - `order=['0', '1', '2']` or `order=label_list`
  2. Convert the `df` column to a `category Dtype` with [`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html)

     - `df.label = pd.Categorical(values=df.label, categories=label_list, ordered=True)`